# Trouble accessing a .txt file.

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, text

I have the following method that is meant to get all the words contained in text file and add them to an array. I think the problem is where my .txt file is located. I am adding it into the project explorer right next to the classes. I have read elsewhere that it is meant to go in your Resource folder, however I think newer versions of XCode no longer creates a resource folder for you. Regardless here is my method:

```
-(void) getWords
{
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WordList" ofType:@"txt"];
 NSString *wordFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

 NSArray* words = [wordFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
 NSLog(@"Found %lu words", (unsigned long)[words count]);
}
```

Could someone help me get this method to find my file? Where can I put the .txt file? Thanks.

Comment: Is `filePath` valid or `nil`? Is `wordFile` valid or `nil`? Is your file really named `WordList.txt` or is really named `wordlist.txt`? Case matters.

Comment: The code looks OK indeed. Don't worry about the resources folder, the file can live anywhere in your bundle. How did you add it to the project?

Comment: It does? I just right clicked supporting files then clicked add file, then selected WordList.txt. Really frustrating it must me something small like that that I did